# Can't find Android build tool with ionic2 cordova

Tags: android, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

when I try to build an APK with

> ionic cordova build android

Suddenly I faced this error

> ```
>   * What went wrong:
>     A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
> ```
>
> No installed build tools found. Install the Android build tools version 19.1.0 or higher.
>           0

I'm sure that a have android build tool from android studio versions (2.1.1 - 22.0.0 - 23.0.0 ) and last version 26.0.1

output of cordova requirements

> Requirements check results for android:
>   Java JDK: installed 1.8.0
>   Android SDK: installed true
>   Android target: not installed 
>   android: Command failed with exit code ENOENT
>   Gradle: installed /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-3.2/bin/gradle
>   Error: Some of requirements check failed

and this the uses sdk in AndroidMaifest.xml file

```
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="25" />
```

**Installed platforms:** android 6.2.3

Comment: what is the output of `cordova requirements`? and `targetSdkVersion` in AndroidManifest xml in your android platform folder?

Comment: ok .. please check the last edit in the post

Comment: What is your Cordova android platform version?

Comment: Installed platforms:
  android 6.2.3

Answer (score 0):

Is your android sdk folder saved on your environment variables?

Try to add your root android SDK folder(something like `C:\android-sdk` or `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\`) to **both** `ANDROID_HOME` and `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` environment variables.

Also add(change it to your current android sdk folder):
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools`
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools`

And maybe
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\26.0.1`

To your system's PATH variable

Then, download **only the binary** for gradle [here](https://gradle.org/releases)

1. Extract it to `C:\Gradle`. Example: `C:\Gradle\gradle-3.5`
2. Add `C:\Gradle\gradle-CURRENTVERSION\bin` to the PATH variable.

After that, restart the computer or re-open any terminal you're running the command

Comment: Sorry but where I spouse can find  ANDROID_HOME &  ANDROID_SDK_ROOT ... notice  that I am using mac os .

Comment: @TawfiekKhalaf you don't find them, you add your Android Root SDK path  to your environment variables named ANDROID_HOME and also named as ANDROID_SDK_ROOT

Comment: how I can do that ?!

Comment: Look [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/106778/how-do-i-set-environment-variables-on-os-x)